# When to use query population in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I will try to ask so that there is a definitive answer. I am currently building an app that displays choose-your-own-adventure style books. In designing my data structure I initially was going to have a model to represent a book, then reference other documents in my database that had the pages and their content using query population. Now, I am considering making the book one giant document in mongo/mongoose. Are there any limits on mongodb or mongoose that prevent me from storing the book as one giant document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a document has 16MB of default size, it'll enough to store giant data.

Comment: So, when you use query population, does that temporarily merge the two documents? If so, would the size restriction still apply?

Comment: If you use population then the property that store the _id will only refer that document, it'll not increase the size of document.